# (C++ Array problem) I want to printout the foods I ordered via numbercode I inputed during DoWhile process

Tags: c++, arrays, do-while

**I will input:** *(The numbers is food code, Y/N is yes/no for do-while)*

```
1
Y
2
Y
3
N
```

Then my **expected output** would be

```
Chicken
Fries
Hotdog
```

Please see my code, it does not print out anything.
My idea would be everytime I inputed a number , it will trigger the switch function, then a variable with the prepared value *(ex:order2 = fries)* will be stored within the array. So when looping it, I will input multiple orders and I want to print them out *(see my expected output above)*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int ordercode;
int i;
int limit;
char yesno;
char allorder[10][100];
string order1="Chicken";
string order2="Fries";
string order3="Hotdog";
do 
{
limit++;
i++;
cout<<" Enter order ";
cin>>ordercode;
switch(ordercode){
    case 1:
        order1 == allorder[i];
        break;
    case 2:
        order2 == allorder[i];
        break;
    case 3:
        order3 == allorder[i];
        break;
}
cout<<"Will you order again?";
cin>>yesno; 
}

while(yesno == 'Y');

for(i = 0; i<limit; i++)
{

    cout <<allorder[i];
    cout<<"\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code with a debugger?

Comment: There is no error , it just dont print out anything at all.

Comment: There seems to be a logical error. Use the debugger to find out why there is no output. Step line by line through your code to find the line that doesn't behave as expected. Check the values of the variables in each step.

Comment: Oof. That hurts my eyes. Try to include indentation, especially when you're going multiple levels deep, please.

Comment: I think the problem would be either the values of the variable are not really stored properly within the array or the for loop(print out rpocess) dont work at all.

Comment: Could you please let us know what you are trying to accomplish with the statement `order1 == allorder[i];` ?

Comment: `int limit` is not a global var, it is not initialized before the first use in `limit++`.

Comment: Im sorry, this is my first question. Sorry , Im new to this platform.

Comment: I tried to run the program with the given input and got a segmentation fault. That's a runtime error. Probably you are accessing the array out of bounds. With a debugger you could find the line where `i < 0` or `i >= 10`.

Comment: Legolas , Im trying to store the value of order1 (which is chicken) in the array.

Comment: The compiler and the linker are two very good tools to find compiler and linker errors but usually they won't help you find runtime errors. You should learn how to use a debugger to analyze the flow of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some of these improvements see how you get on. Your ideas are fine, but you are getting lots of the details wrong.

```
int i = 0;

int limit = 0;

string allorders[10];

allorders[i] = "Chicken";

allorders[i] = "Fries";

allorders[i] = "Hotdog";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not zero-initializing i. Simply writing

```
int i;
```

will not necessarily set i to zero. This may cause segmentation faults when you try to use i as an index into an array -- i could be *anything*, so it could go way out of bounds. You need to write

```
int i = 0;
```

Do the same with limit.

Also,

```
allorder[i] = order1;
```

should be that line. Additionally, why are you declaring allorder as 10x100 if you're indexing it by one index, i? Remove one of the dimensions. Additionally, make allorder into an array of strings, not chars, since you're assigning strings to its elements.

You are already using C++, so there is no reason to use old C constructs when alternatives exist. Use vector, not a char or string array. You can look up how to use these C++ features, which are much more flexible and capable than what you're using now, in a lot of different places. The sites cppreference.com and cplusplus.com are two big ones that I use.

Oh, and use indentation! Please! :)

Comment: He has two dimensions because it is over char, and he wants to store an array of strings (and uses the wrong code for that).

Comment: I get the other things you said, but what do you mean about "allorder as 10x100 if youre indexing it by one index? remove one of the dimensions"

Comment: Ok, you declared allorder as char[10][100]. That makes it a 2D array. That means you (usually) access it with two indices, like allorder[i][j]. You're trying to access it with just one index, i, like allorder[i]. That means you should make it a one dimensional array, of strings. Like "string allorder[100];".

Comment: Yes, you are right. Looks like I search the wrong thread with solution before. Should have asked here sooner.